# Bootstrap accordion toggle triggered from onclick behave weird

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I want to trigger toggle function of Bootstrap accordion on click on image map area. Trouble is that it behaves strangely. When I click on some area first time, all accordion elements are shown, then on second click, all become collapsed, and finally on third click and later it works as expected. I have created example on jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/adnank/SHdJm/4/).

I have tried different setups, but this one seems to be working most closely as what is expected.

```
<div class="accordion" id="faq">
<img src="http://www.vero.at/themes/vero/images/en/Leistungsspektrum.jpg" alt="Leistungssprektrum" id="kreis" usemap="#map1">
    <map name="map1">
          <area shape="poly" coords="220,240,290,135,365,175,366,238" alt="Risikoanalyse" onmouseover="document.getElementById('kreis').src='http://www.vero.at/themes/vero/images/en/Risikoanalyse.jpg'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('kreis').src='http://www.vero.at/themes/vero/images/en/Leistungsspektrum.jpg'" onclick="jQuery('#collapseOne').collapse('toggle');jQuery('#collapseTwo').collapse('hide');jQuery('#collapseThree').collapse('hide');jQuery('#collapseFour').collapse('hide');jQuery('#collapseFive').collapse('hide');jQuery('#collapseSix').collapse('hide');">
          <area shape="poly" coords="266,252,377,252,377,193,420,193,420,288,267,288" alt="Deckungskonzept" onmouseover="document.getElementById('kreis').src='http://www.vero.at/themes/vero/images/en/Deckungskonzept.jpg'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('kreis').src='http://www.vero.at/themes/vero/images/en/Leistungsspektrum.jpg'" onclick="jQuery('#collapseOne').collapse('hide');jQuery('#collapseTwo').collapse('toggle');jQuery('#collapseThree').collapse('hide');jQuery('#collapseFour').collapse('hide');jQuery('#collapseFive').collapse('hide');jQuery('#collapseSix').collapse('hide');">
          <area shape="poly" coords="270,340,400,340,450,302,400,423,360,420,356,376,276,378" alt="Ausschreibung" onmouseover="document.getElementById('kreis').src='http://www.vero.at/themes/vero/images/en/Ausschreibung.jpg'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('kreis').src='http://www.vero.at/themes/vero/images/en/Leistungsspektrum.jpg'" onclick="jQuery('#collapseOne').collapse('hide');jQuery('#collapseTwo').collapse('hide');jQuery('#collapseThree').collapse('toggle');jQuery('#collapseFour').collapse('hide');jQuery('#collapseFive').collapse('hide');jQuery('#collapseSix').collapse('hide');" style="cursor: pointer;">
          <area shape="poly" coords="207,395,330,395,345,465,207,465" alt="Vergabe" onmouseover="document.getElementById('kreis').src='http://www.vero.at/themes/vero/images/en/Vergabe.jpg'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('kreis').src='http://www.vero.at/themes/vero/images/en/Leistungsspektrum.jpg'" onclick="jQuery('#collapseOne').collapse('hide');jQuery('#collapseTwo').collapse('hide');jQuery('#collapseThree').collapse('hide');jQuery('#collapseFour').collapse('toggle');jQuery('#collapseFive').collapse('hide');jQuery('#collapseSix').collapse('hide');" style="cursor: pointer;">
          <area shape="poly" coords="48,320,222,314,220,350,188,417,188,474,95,434,47,329" alt="Vertragsbetreuung" onmouseover="document.getElementById('kreis').src='http://www.vero.at/themes/vero/images/en/Vertragsbetreuung.jpg'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('kreis').src='http://www.vero.at/themes/vero/images/en/Leistungsspektrum.jpg'" onclick="jQuery('#collapseOne').collapse('hide');jQuery('#collapseTwo').collapse('hide');jQuery('#collapseThree').collapse('hide');jQuery('#collapseFour').collapse('hide');jQuery('#collapseFive').collapse('toggle');jQuery('#collapseSix').collapse('hide');" style="cursor: pointer;">
          <area shape="poly" coords="11,313,11,210,66,98,92,115,90,235,189,235,189,289,52,310" alt="Schadensabwicklung" onmouseover="document.getElementById('kreis').src='http://www.vero.at/themes/vero/images/en/Schadensabwicklung.jpg'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('kreis').src='http://www.vero.at/themes/vero/images/en/Leistungsspektrum.jpg'" onclick="jQuery('#collapseOne').collapse('hide');jQuery('#collapseTwo').collapse('hide');jQuery('#collapseThree').collapse('hide');jQuery('#collapseFour').collapse('hide');jQuery('#collapseFive').collapse('hide');jQuery('#collapseSix').collapse('toggle');" style="cursor: hand;">
    </map>          
<div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#faq" href="#collapseOne">
            1. Risk analyses
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
            Lorem ipsum
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#faq" href="#collapseTwo">
            2. Coverage concepts
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
            Lorem ipsum
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#faq" href="#collapseThree">
            3. Tender
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-body collapse">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
            Lorem ipsum
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#faq" href="#collapseFour">
            4. Authorisation
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFour" class="accordion-body collapse">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
            Lorem ipsum
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#faq" href="#collapseFive">
            5. Contract handling
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFive" class="accordion-body collapse">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
            Lorem ipsum
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#faq" href="#collapseSix">
            6. Claim settlement
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseSix" class="accordion-body collapse">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
            Lorem ipsum
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've rewritten the onclick parts.. It's shorter, but the strange behaviour isn't gone :s [my atempt](http://jsfiddle.net/SHdJm/6/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. When you work with bootstrap collapse plugin and toggle buttons are groupped you don't need to call collapse method for each item, just for one. So `onclick` handler can look like: `onclick="jQuery('#collapseOne').collapse('toggle');"`. But in this case you also need to initialize toggle parent option for each area.
2. You can attach more than one toggle button for one content block. So `onclick` handler is not neccessary and can be relaced with `data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#faq" data-target="#collapseOne"`

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/SHdJm/8/

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I have tried to use data controls, but obviously I did it improperly, so another option was to use JS :)

Comment: I know you're not supposed to just say 'thanks', but you helped me fix a bug that I'd been working on for hours.  It's always the dumb little things.  I was 'attaching' my toggle code to each accordion as they were created dynamically, which made every other accordion not work (and by not work, I mean the icons wouldn't change).  So, thank you!

Comment: Bless you :) It was exactly what I was looking for too